# unable to get ng-model value in controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner and trying hard to learn Angular. I am stuck at a point where I need ng-model value in my controller. I can see that a lot of people had already asked this question but most of them never got a correct answer. 
This is my code

```
<body ng-app="newApp">
<div ng-controller="myController2">
    <input type="text" name="name" required ng-model="nameMy" id="new">
    <button ng-click="showValues">Submit</button>
    <p> {{nameMy}} </p>
</div>
</body>
```

**Angular**

```
var newApp = angular.module('newApp', []);
newApp.controller('myController2', function($scope){
    $scope.showValues = function(){
        console.log($scope.nameMy);
    }
    $scope.showValues();
});
```

I $scope.nameMy is giving me undefined, I have also tried the `dot` [rule](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html) in model name but nothing is working. I would appreciate if anybody can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `()` after the showvalues since it is a function

```
 <button ng-click="showValues()">Submit</button>
```

Working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/2xGPNmkdlLz4bzjxuhvj?p=preview)

Comment: I am doing `$scope.test = $scope.nameMy;` and accessing it by `<p> {{test}} </p>` I am getting nothing. any ideas?